# Shiny app deployment error

Tags: r, shiny

I am getting an error after successful deployment of my shiny app, although I have the data file included in the directory with the server and UI. Below is what I pulled from the log file.

I tried changing the name of the app, without parentheses or spaces, doesn't work.

```
2017-12-10T09:51:08.863226+00:00 shinyapps[246767]:     70: listify
2017-12-10T09:51:08.860240+00:00 shinyapps[246767]: Warning: Error in lapply: object 'Dat' not found
2017-12-10T09:51:08.863225+00:00 shinyapps[246767]:     71: lapply
2017-12-10T09:51:08.863224+00:00 shinyapps[246767]: Stack trace (innermost first):
2017-12-10T09:51:08.863227+00:00 shinyapps[246767]:     69: choicesWithNames
2017-12-10T09:51:08.863227+00:00 shinyapps[246767]:     68: selectInput
2017-12-10T09:51:08.863228+00:00 shinyapps[246767]:     67: tag
2017-12-10T09:51:08.863229+00:00 shinyapps[246767]:     66: tags$form
2017-12-10T09:51:08.863230+00:00 shinyapps[246767]:     63: div
2017-12-10T09:51:08.863231+00:00 shinyapps[246767]:     62: sidebarPanel
2017-12-10T09:51:08.863232+00:00 shinyapps[246767]:     60: tag
2017-12-10T09:51:08.863231+00:00 shinyapps[246767]:     61: sidebarLayout
2017-12-10T09:51:08.863234+00:00 shinyapps[246767]:     55: bootstrapPage
2017-12-10T09:51:08.863232+00:00 shinyapps[246767]:     59: tags$div
2017-12-10T09:51:08.863233+00:00 shinyapps[246767]:     58: div
2017-12-10T09:51:08.863234+00:00 shinyapps[246767]:     57: tagList
2017-12-10T09:51:08.863234+00:00 shinyapps[246767]:     56: attachDependencies
2017-12-10T09:51:08.863229+00:00 shinyapps[246767]:     65: tag
2017-12-10T09:51:08.863235+00:00 shinyapps[246767]:     54: fluidPage
2017-12-10T09:51:08.863230+00:00 shinyapps[246767]:     64: tags$div
2017-12-10T09:51:08.863235+00:00 shinyapps[246767]:     53: shinyUI
2017-12-10T09:51:08.863236+00:00 shinyapps[246767]:     13: runApp
2017-12-10T09:51:08.863236+00:00 shinyapps[246767]:     12: fn
2017-12-10T09:51:08.863237+00:00 shinyapps[246767]:     11: doTryCatch
2017-12-10T09:51:08.863237+00:00 shinyapps[246767]:     10: tryCatchOne
2017-12-10T09:51:08.863237+00:00 shinyapps[246767]:      9: tryCatchList
2017-12-10T09:51:08.863238+00:00 shinyapps[246767]:      8: tryCatch
2017-12-10T09:51:08.863238+00:00 shinyapps[246767]:      7: connect$retry
2017-12-10T09:51:08.863239+00:00 shinyapps[246767]:      6: eval
2017-12-10T09:51:08.863239+00:00 shinyapps[246767]:      5: eval
2017-12-10T09:51:08.863240+00:00 shinyapps[246767]:      4: eval
2017-12-10T09:51:08.863240+00:00 shinyapps[246767]:      3: eval
2017-12-10T09:51:08.863241+00:00 shinyapps[246767]:      2: eval.parent
2017-12-10T09:51:08.863241+00:00 shinyapps[246767]:      1: local
2017-12-10T09:51:08.863575+00:00 shinyapps[246767]: Error : An error has occurred. Check your logs or contact the app author for clarification.
2017-12-10T09:55:31.158124+00:00 shinyapps[246767]: Listening on http://127.0.0.1:35243
2017-12-10T09:55:31.158123+00:00 shinyapps[246767]: 
2017-12-10T09:56:33.909383+00:00 shinyapps[246767]: Server version: 1.5.10-6
2017-12-10T09:56:33.909385+00:00 shinyapps[246767]: LANG: en_US.UTF-8
2017-12-10T09:56:33.909421+00:00 shinyapps[246767]: R version: 3.4.1
2017-12-10T09:56:33.909422+00:00 shinyapps[246767]: shiny version: 1.0.5
2017-12-10T09:56:33.909423+00:00 shinyapps[246767]: rmarkdown version: NA
2017-12-10T09:56:33.909423+00:00 shinyapps[246767]: knitr version: NA
2017-12-10T09:56:33.909441+00:00 shinyapps[246767]: RJSONIO version: NA
2017-12-10T09:56:33.909442+00:00 shinyapps[246767]: htmltools version: 0.3.6
2017-12-10T09:56:34.122783+00:00 shinyapps[246767]: 
2017-12-10T09:56:34.031987+00:00 shinyapps[246767]: Using jsonlite for JSON processing
2017-12-10T09:56:33.909440+00:00 shinyapps[246767]: jsonlite version: 1.5
2017-12-10T09:56:34.122791+00:00 shinyapps[246767]: Starting R with process ID: '46'
2017-12-10T09:56:34.153091+00:00 shinyapps[246767]: 
2017-12-10T09:56:34.153093+00:00 shinyapps[246767]: Listening on http://127.0.0.1:45596
```

Answer (score 0):

your second log has an error that may be causing it all to fail:

`Error in lapply: object 'Dat' not found`